# How to add condition on action of a resource block in CHEF?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I created one resource which has two actions.

Let's say action:A1 and action:A2.
Iam able to call them in one single resource block(**test**) like this :

```
test 'Testing the actions' do
    action [:a1 ,:a2]
    only_if {::File.exists?"/tmp/action_exist.txt"}
end
```

It is working fine.But what if I want to add the condition on the action like this

> Check condition only for action :A1. and simply run action :A2 irrespective of condition.

I tried like this :

```
test 'Testing the actions' do
    action [:A1 ,:A2]
    if (action.first=="A1")
            puts "yes"
            only_if {::File.exists?"/tmp/action_exist.txt" }
    end
```

end

But it's not working.
It is executing this condition for both the actions

Comment: It seems both elements on action are symbols, can you compare them as `action.first == :A1`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Sorry, but it didn't help.
`test 'Testing the actions' do
        action [:a1 ,:a2]
        if (action.first == ":a1")
                  only_if { ::File.exists?"/tmp/action_exist.txt" }
        end
end
`
**output**
` * test[Testing the actions] action a1
    * file[/tmp/temp1.txt] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * test[Testing the actions] action a2
    * file[/tmp/temp2.txt] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
`
Means it's not skipping for both

Comment: Not as a string. As in the example I added. `':A1'` -> string, `:A1` -> symbol.

Comment: @SebastianPalma..Yes  but this time , it's skipping for both
`   test[Testing the actions] action a1 (skipped due to not_if)
   test[Testing the actions] action a2 (skipped due to not_if)`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the condition is known at compile time. If the condition is known at compile time, you could write something like:

```
test 'Testing the action' do
  if ::File.exists?('/tmp/action_exist.txt')
    action [:A1, :A2]
  else
    action [:A2]
  end
end
```

But that's **only** if your recipes are not fiddling with `/tmp/action_exist.txt` during the run. If the status of `/tmp/action_exist.txt` might change during convergence, then you may need to do something fancier. For instance, you could notify the resource to perform `:A1` immediately in some resource the precedes the resource. That's not something I have done, so you will probably need to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Chef works. The resource body isn't a script that is run each action.